# Truncate SQL Server transaction log file

Tags: sql-server

In my local C: drive I have a `ldf` file for a database that is hosted on one of our servers. I have a local copy of one of the databases that is 1 gb and a `ldf` (log file) of that database that is 16gb. It is eating up a lot of my local space on my hard drive. I would like to truncate that file. A lot of what I read online is don't, but it seems that they are talking about files on the server that the database is on. That isn't the case here, it is on my local machine.

The location of the file on my machine is:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL10_50.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\DATA
```

How come I have a copy of that log file locally and also that database locally?

How would I go about truncating this file?

Thanks!

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Go to the Object Explorer pane in SSMS and right click on the database in question.  Choose tasks -> shrink -> files.  Change the file type option to Log, click the "Reorganize pages before releasing unused space" option, and set the value to 1 MB.  Hit OK.

If this doesn't work, check to see if your database is set up with a Full database recover model.  Right click the database and go to properties.  Choose Options, and check the Recover model option.  Set to simple (if you can!!!), then shrink the logs.

Comment: That is shrinking the files on the actual server that the database is on, not my local drive.

Comment: Let me make sure I'm understanding this.  You have a local copy of a database located elsewhere.  Is your local copy attached to a local SQL Server instance?

Comment: From my understanding. I am new to sql server, so I am not sure why it is there really. It is under the directory that I listed in my original post, on my local machine. It is also on the server. i am not sure if they are the same or what the deal is.

Comment: Yeah, no idea why it's on your box.  You'd have to ask someone there.  Have you tried logging into SSMS with your local computer name as the server instead of the remote server?

Comment: I am uninstalling. We had to do some funky stuff to get a asp mvc app to work a month ago. I am guessing that screwed things all up.

Comment: I just wanted to give an update. I had forgotten that I put one of our database on my localhost, so that I could run a mvc app. I actually uninstalled everything twice to get everything to work. It occured to me that I had that locally. I used the method that you mentioned and it worked perfectly and shrunk the log file.

Thanks!

Comment: Great to hear it!  Literally just went through an issue like this last week.

Answer (score 1):

The another option you can try is to use WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY:

```
BACKUP LOG  databasename  WITH TRUNCATE_ONLY
DBCC SHRINKFILE (  adventureworks_Log, 1)
```

but don't try this option in live environment, the far better option is to set database in simple recovery. see the below command to do this:

```
ALTER DATABASE mydatabase SET RECOVERY SIMPLE
 DBCC SHRINKFILE (adventureworks_Log, 1)
```